# Playground start in the developer environment

Tags: hyperledger-composer

How to Start Playground in the developer environment? Please provide the document.

I am following the developer installation guide: https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/tutorials/developer-guide.html

If you want to run the Playground locally, install the composer-playground using the following command.

```
npm install -g composer-playground
```

I don't see how to start the playground after that.

Thank you, Christo. I am able to install now. I installed playground first and installed all other composer components(npm install -g composer-cli,npm install -g generator-hyper ledger-composer,npm install -g composer-rest-server). Problem is now, I am not able to deploy .bna using admin credentials for composer-rest-server. Next tried deploying using the PeerAdmin for composer-rest-server, which was successful.

Now the issue is not allowing the asset creation (Throwing, the asset cannot be created via PeerAdmin). What is the proper way to set up the developer environment plus playground in the same environment?

Answer (score 0):

The instructions are in the [tutorial](https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/installing/using-playground-locally.html) documentation. Basically, you need to install and start the Hyperledger Fabric network, configured for Composer. It will launch the playground in your favorite browser.

After the first time you run it, you can start/stop the network with `composer.sh` to re-start, and `composer.sh stop` (from the directory into which you installed fabric-tools) to shutdown all the Fabric and Composer docker images. Once started, you can open `http://localhost:8080/login` to start the playground.

Comment: Thank you, Christo. I am able to install now. I installed playground first and installed all other composer components(npm install -g composer-cli,npm install -g generator-hyperledger-composer,npm install -g composer-rest-server). Problem is now, I am not able to deploy .bna using admin credentials for composer-rest-server. Next tried deploying using the PeerAdmin for composer-rest-server, which was successful.

Comment: yes, I was confused too about the credentials needed to deploy. Glad you're all set.

Comment: @christo4ferris - I am trying to restart composer playground locally, I try typing `composer.sh` and it says its an invalid command.  I then just type `composer` which works; but says I need to pass in at least one parameter, which there isn't any for restarting.  When I goto localhost:8080 I get a 404 error. Any ideas?

Comment: I am not able to invoke rest command with the PeerAdmin credentials. Please suggest

Comment: @christo4ferris , I am not able to invoke rest command with the PeerAdmin credentials. Please suggest

Comment: The composer.sh script is in the fabric-tools repository that you cloned during the initial install. The 'composer' command is actually a node.js module you installed with 'npm install -g composer-cli'. They each serve a different purpose. The name similarity is probably something that should be addressed to make things less confusing.

If you are in the fabric-tools directory, and the composer.sh script is present, then likely you just need to provide the relative path because you haven't got the fabric-tools directory in your $PATH environment variable. Try './composer.sh' instead.